# RestSharp/Json.NET Serialize Array as JSON Object

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, restsharp

I have a slight situation. I'm interacting with a web service using RestSharp, where the service is requiring me to send the following as part of the request:

```
{
    "a":"a value",
    "b":"b value"
}
```

Which is all fine and dandy, because you could simply use a `class` such as this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

However, ***I do not know know the property names at runtime***. Therefore, I attempted to use an `ExpandoObject`, but of course, this simply serialized as a JSON array:

```
[
    "a":"a value",
    "b":"b value"
]
```

So, it would seem that I need to be able to serialize (***and deserialize***) a `Dictionary` (or `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`) as a JSON object (in other words, use curly braces instead of a brackets).

Does anyone know how I might do this, preferably by using a Json.NET attribute, such that the functionality may be reused elsewhere?

Comment: this was asked here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739094/serializing-deserializing-dictionary-of-objects-with-json-net

Comment: That posters question was about the details of how to serialize a dictionary of complex objects into a Json array of Json objects. My question is about how to serialize a dictionary of simple key value pairs into a single Json object: where each key is a property name, and each value is a property value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about using a JObject?

```
var obj = new JObject();

obj["One"] = "Value One";
obj["Two"] = "Value Two";
obj["Three"] = "Value Three";

var serialized = obj.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

gives you

```
{"One":"Value One","Two":"Value Two","Three":"Value Three"}
```

Comment: It's always the simple things that get you, right? Am I the only one? I'll test this and get back to you... :)

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed it to. Since I wanted to keep my serialization code separate from my domain, I simply looped over the key value pairs I wanted to serialize as an object, and assigned each value to the corresponding JObject's index.

Comment: While this wasn't the `Attribute` solution I was looking for, one could probably adapt some solution from this, using a custom converter.

Comment: Agreed with @ChristopherHarris, I can't deserialize using this (or `ExpandoObject`) -- I just get empty objects back

Comment: try JObject.ToString(), you can specify your formatting and converters here too

Answer (score 0):

Use JavascripSerializer object from .net class libs. It supports reflection on the object it is serializing

see [msdn docs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx&ei=EvCNT9PGLca-8APGtYWfCw&usg=AFQjCNGMTMT3jhFYETV1ayJ_ym7Xqz5gBw&sig2=KMjm0638Pz3KZC7_Ju81-g)