# Json deserializing object as Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I'm serializing object let's call it `X` to Json, one of fields in `X` is type of object (here i assign different classes instances).

```
public object value
{
    get;
    set;
 }
```

So after deserialization I get `value` as `Dictionary<propertyName, value>`

```
["x", "valX"]
["y", "valY"]
```

I understand why this works that way, so my question is what is the best way to create propper class instance according to this `value` I can create new instane and assign propertieces:

```
new A() 
{
    x = value["x"],
    y = value["y"],
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But is there any beter way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744505/6756334

It is solved with json.net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) an awesome lib for serializing and deserializing json in c#